# Ansible: Verbose output for modules

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm looking for a way to get a bit more verbose output from Ansible modules for *successful* execution, but the only example where that appears to be implemented is the shell module, which allows to register and later print stdout and stderr.
While this would be a work-around, breaking out to a shell is not good practice if built-in Ansible modules exist.

To give an example, where more verbose output from a module would be useful:

```
- name: upgrade all packages
  yum: name=* state=latest
```

This updates all packages using the yum module. However, it doesn't show what (if anything) was updated.

Similar behaviour can be observed in other modules. So the actual question: Is there any Ansible switch/setting which can force more verbose output for *a single task* in a playbook? (I'd like to cherry pick where I get verbose output and avoid noise from everything else.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @xeroqu, I can answer that myself now:

```
  - name: upgrade all packages
    yum: name=* state=latest
    register: result
  - name: Show output
    when: result|succeeded
    debug: msg="{{ result.results }}"
```

The key is in `{{result.results}}` as opposed to `{{result.stdout_lines}}`. More precisely, modules appear to return a dictionary with (at least?) the following content:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
   "msg": {
       "changed": false,
       "msg": "",
       "rc": 0,
       "results": [
          "Nothing to do here, all packages are up to date"
       ]
   }
}
```

That definitely gives me the verbosity I was looking for, which can be applied on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 6):

One idea would be having another task that would print the output of the previous task if it succeeds. I didn't test but something like this might work:

```
 - name: upgrade all packages
   yum: name=* state=latest
   register: result
 - name: Show output
   when: result|succeeded
   debug: msg="{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: That was *almost* spot on, thanks. I'll give it an upvote because it got me into the right direction. Will answer my own question in a second.